# Issues with ng2-charts

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to add charts to my project in angular 2 but it can't find the chart.js file.
those are the errors:

```
1. EXCEPTION: ng2-charts configuration issue: Embedding Chart.js lib is mandatory

2. Error: ng2-charts configuration issue: Embedding Chart.js lib is mandatory
    at BaseChartDirective.getChartBuilder (charts.js:70)
    at BaseChartDirective.refresh (charts.js:113)
    at BaseChartDirective.ngOnInit (charts.js:18)
    at _View_BarChartDetailComponent0.detectChangesInternal (BarChartDetailComponent.ngfactory.js:151)
    at _View_BarChartDetailComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12061)
    at _View_AdminPageStatusComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:12087)
    at _View_AdminPageStatusComponent0.AppView.detectChangesInternal (core.umd.js:12072)
    at _View_AdminPageStatusComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12061)
    at _View_AdminPageStatusComponent_Host0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:12087)
    at _View_AdminPageStatusComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChangesInternal (core.umd.js:12072)
```

I added this to the systemjs.config.js file:

```
map: {
    'ng2-charts': 'https://npmcdn.com/ng2-charts@1.4.0'
},
packages: {
    'ng2-charts': {
        main: 'ng2-charts.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

and I added this to the index.js:

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

and also added this to the app.module:

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
```

please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, Add like this to the **`System.config.js`**

```
map: {
 'ng2-charts': 'npm:ng2-charts'
}

packages: {
'ng2-charts': {
      main: 'ng2-charts.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
 }
}
```

and then in your module,

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
```

Comment: I still have problems, but now I have other problems... this id the first one: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at chart.js:4. this is the second: (index):31 Error: TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function

Comment: did you sort this out?

Comment: I solved the first error but the second error still alive. the error is: Error: TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was right. I figured out that my chart.js wasn't inserted to the project well.

Comment: @RandomGuy17 Did you ever a console error stating `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at chart.js:4`?